# Understanding the core dump after Segmentation Fault | Phalcon + Php + Apache

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, apache2, phalcon, coredump

I have managed to get the Core dump after a segmentation fault caused in an env that has

- Phalcon 1.3.1
- Php 5.5.9
- Apache 2.4.7

Running on

- Ubuntu 14.04

Core dump : http://pastebin.com/KeWipxU9

Can someone help me to analyse what could be happening here please ?

At first I thought it was caused by opcache, but I the issue seems to be present even after disabling opcache.

Comment: At a quick glance, you seem to have run out of memory and or storage